spark structured streaming kafka consumer
   SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaDirectKafkaWordCount");
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(2));

        Set<String> topicsSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("test-events"));
        Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
        kafkaParams.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        kafkaParams.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test-group1");
        kafkaParams.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);

        // Create direct kafka stream with brokers and topics
        JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                jssc,
                LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe(topicsSet, kafkaParams));

        // Get the lines, split them into words, count the words and print
        JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(ConsumerRecord::value);
        JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(x -> Arrays.asList(SPACE.split(x)).iterator());
        JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCounts = words.mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<>(s, 1))
                .reduceByKey((i1, i2) -> i1 + i2);
        wordCounts.print();

        // Start the computation
        jssc.start();
        jssc.awaitTermination();

      <dependencies>
        <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

Getting error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/StringDeserializer
    at org.example.JavaDirectKafkaWordCount.main(JavaDirectKafkaWordCount.java:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.sca

